# Function that i want to substract R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have this formula in R, i want to be able to apply it to a different number of value without rewriting it again. e.g: 6 price comparisons instead of 4. How can i do that?
i have been doing is this way, but when i want to compare to different lags and leads, I have to rewrite it

```
a<- for (i in price [sP+1]:length(price)){
      if (price[i] < price[i-1] & price[i] < price[i-2] & 
          price[i] < price[i-3] & price[i] < price[i-4] &
          price[i] < price[i+1] & price[i] < price[i+2] &
          price[i] < price[i+3] & price[i] < price[i+4]) 
    }
```

Comment: I've added a closing curly brace that appeared to be missing from your original post?  Have I got it right?  The format was so awkward it's difficult to tell...  Please post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: It looks as if you want to flag the ith element of `price` if it is the highest value in the subset of `price` from element (i-n) to element (i+n).  Correct?

Comment: (1) Within an `if` conditional, you should only use `&&`/`||` (double), *unless* you use `&`/`|` within `any` or `all` or some function that reduces it to always length 1. You think you're fine since you're subsetting with `[i]`, but there are other differences with `&` (e.g., short-circuiting), so this is risky code. (2) Is there supposed to be code that runs if the `if` conditional is true? This is not valid R code. (3) This can likely be done whole vectors at a time, using subsets, lags, leads, etc.

Comment: i want it to be the lowest price

Answer (score 0):

You could check the differences around price[i].  e.g.

```
price <- c(27, 30,  4, 13,  2, 19, 25, 28, 26,  8)

# Say you want to check around i=5:

lo <- price[5] - price[1:4]
-25 -28  -2 -11
hi <- price[5] - price[6:9]
-17 -23 -26 -24
both <- c(lo, hi)
all(both < 0)
TRUE
```

You could wrap that in a function that passes the price vector, the target price index number and the lo/hi ranges as parameters, then return the output from the `all` function.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help but have prices dating back for 20 years, so it has to check every value for the above condition